# CMake module to make executable as small as possible

Tags: cmake

I wrote this .cmake script when I needed to make smallest possible executables. It makes CMake prefer static libraries, and adds custom command to strip and UPX the end result. I used it only with MinGW on Windows with MSYS2.

My questions:

1. Can this be made more short and readable?
2. Are my checks portable enough?
3. Any way to handle MSVC?

example `main.c`

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    if(!glfwInit())
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    GLenum code = glewInit();
    if(code != GLEW_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "[GLEW Error](%d): %s\n", code, glewGetErrorString(code));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

example `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(staticExe LANGUAGES C)
include(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ReallySmall.cmake)

prefer_static_libs()
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(GLFW3 NAMES glfw glfw3 REQUIRED)
restore_preferred_libs()
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

set(INCLUDE_DIRS ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(LIBS GLEW::GLEW ${GLFW3_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 main.c)

make_small_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})
add_static_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} "GLEW_STATIC")

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

`ReallySmall.cmake`

```
##
#   How to use: 
#   include(ReallySmall.cmake)
#
#   prefer_static_libs()
#   find_package(STATIC_LIBS)
#   restore_preferred_libs()
#   find_package(SHARED_LIBS)
#
#   add_executable(MY_EXE)
#   make_small_executable(MY_EXE)
#   target_link_libraries(...)
##


function(add_static_definitions TARGET_NAME)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
        set(IS_MARKED -1)
        list(FIND _SMALL_EXECUTABLES ${TARGET_NAME} IS_MARKED)
        if(NOT (IS_MARKED EQUAL -1))
            list(REMOVE_AT ARGV 0)
            foreach(DEFINITION IN LISTS ARGV)
                target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC ${DEFINITION})
            endforeach()
        endif()
    endif()
endfunction()

function(make_small_executable)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
        foreach(TARGET_NAME IN LISTS ARGV)

            list(APPEND _SMALL_EXECUTABLES ${TARGET_NAME})
            set(_SMALL_EXECUTABLES ${_SMALL_EXECUTABLES} PARENT_SCOPE)

            # We will run UPX only if we have strip
            if(CMAKE_STRIP)
                add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD 
                                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_STRIP} ${STRIP_FLAGS} $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET_NAME}>)
                if(SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE)
                    add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD 
                                       COMMAND ${SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE} ${SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE_FLAGS} $<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET_NAME}>)
                endif()
            endif()

            # Now add some linker flags
            get_target_property(TARGET_LANG ${TARGET_NAME} LINKER_LANGUAGE)
            if(TARGET_LANG STREQUAL "C")
                if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
                    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} "-static-libgcc")
                    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} "-static-libasan" "-static-libtsan" "-static-liblsan" "-static-libubsan" "-static-libmpx" "-static-libmpxwrappers")
                endif()
            elseif(TARGET_LANG STREQUAL "CXX")
                if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
                    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} "-static-libgcc" "-static-libstdc++")
                    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} "-static-libasan" "-static-libtsan" "-static-liblsan" "-static-libubsan" "-static-libmpx" "-static-libmpxwrappers")
                endif()
            endif()

        endforeach()
    endif()
endfunction(make_small_executable)

function(prefer_static_libs)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
        set(_OLD_FIND_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES} PARENT_SCOPE)
        if(MINGW)
            list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dll")
            list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dll.a")
        elseif(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
            list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".so")
        elseif(APPLE)
            list(REMOVE_ITEM CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".dylib")
        endif()
            set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES} PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endfunction(prefer_static_libs)

function(restore_preferred_libs)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
        set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${_OLD_FIND_SUFFIXES} PARENT_SCOPE)
    endif()
endfunction(restore_preferred_libs)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "MinSizeRel")
    # Find needed utilities

    set(STRIP_FLAGS "-s" CACHE STRING "Remove all symbols")
    set(SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE_FLAGS "-9q" CACHE STRING "Quiet max compression")
    mark_as_advanced(STRIP_FLAGS)
    mark_as_advanced(SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE_FLAGS)

    find_package(SelfPackers) # Find UPX, it should be somewhere in PATH
endif()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas about how to reduce the complexity and thereby increase the readability of your module's code:

1. You could merge `prefer_static_libs()`, `find_package()` and `restore_preferred_libs()` into a single dedicated macro like

   ```
   macro(rs_find_package)
       set(_OLD_FIND_SUFFIXES ${CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES})
       set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ".lib" ".a" ".so" ".sl" ".dylib" ".dll.a")
       find_package(${ARGN})
       set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES ${_OLD_FIND_SUFFIXES})
       unset(_OLD_FIND_SUFFIXES)
   endmacro(rs_find_package)
   ```

   - The simplified version [`CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html) preferring static libraries on all platforms is taken from [`Test/OutDir/OutDir.cmake`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Tests/OutDir/OutDir.cmake)
   - In your use case I would recommend to prefer static libraries for all configurations to simplify the usage in multi-configuration environments like Visual Studio (otherwise we have to run [`find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/find_package.html) twice)
2. You could move the post build steps into its own CMake script like

   **cmake/ReallySmallPostBuild.cmake**

   ```
   if(EXECUTE_POST_BUILD)
       if (CMAKE_STRIP)
           execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_STRIP} -s ${TARGET_FILE})
       endif()
       if(SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE)
           execute_process(COMMAND ${SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE} -9q ${TARGET_FILE})
       endif()
   endif()
   ```

   **cmake/ReallySmall.cmake**

   ```
   ...
   add_custom_command(
       TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} 
       POST_BUILD 
           COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} 
               -D EXECUTE_POST_BUILD=$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>
               -D TARGET_FILE="$<TARGET_FILE:${TARGET_NAME}>"
               -D CMAKE_STRIP="${CMAKE_STRIP}"
               -D SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE="${SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE}"
               -P ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ReallySmallPostBuild.cmake
   )
   ...
   ```

   - This works also for multi-configuration environments, since the check for "Should I execute post build steps?" is inside the external script
   - I've moved your `STRIP_FLAGS` and `SELF_PACKER_FOR_EXECUTABLE_FLAGS` a fixed parameters directly into the external script
3. You could simplify your `add_static_definitions()` with [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html):

   **cmake/ReallySmall.cmake**

   ```
   ...
   function(add_static_definitions TARGET_NAME)
       target_compile_definitions(${TARGET_NAME} PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:${ARGN}>)
   endfunction()
   ...
   ```

   Or if you take my recommendation from the top to always prefer static libs, I think you should directly put those definition declarations to

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
   ...
   target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "GLEW_STATIC")
   ...
   ```

   - I did not see the necessity for the `_SMALL_EXECUTABLES` crosschecks, so they are removed here